# Require derived classes to provide a static const value

Tags: c++, inheritance, pure-virtual, compile-time-constant

I have a base class and derived classes. The base class uses pure virtual methods to require the derived classes to implement methods - otherwise it doesn't compile. Classic.

Can I also require from the base class that the derived classes give a value for a constant ? It has to be a compile-time constant, but also it has to be a compilation error if they don't give a value for the constant. It is also static to each derived class since it is instance-independent.

I have seen answers suggesting to write a pure virtual getter which returns a value, but the getter could then have dynamic code with changing behavior depending on some conditions.  I really mean this to be a lifelong constant. Also, since it's not static in that solution, there might be one instance of that constant value for each instance of the derived classes, and that's a waste of memory.

Basically like a name or id. Here is what it would sort of look like, but of course that doesn't compile for multiple reasons.

```
class Base
{
     Base();
    ~Base();
     virtual void doSomething() = 0;
     /* Unknown for Base, meant as an abstract / pure virtual class,
        but required for all derived classes. */
     static const int id;
}

class VariantA : public Base
{
    VariantA();
    ~VariantA();

    static const int id = 215684;
    void doSomething() {...}
    SomeType someData;
};

class VariantB : public Base
{
    VariantB();
    ~VariantB();

    static const int id = 6451322;

    void doSomething() {... /* do it differently than VariantA */}
    
    SomeOtherType someOtherData;
};
```

`id` never changes and does not depend on the instance, but does depend on which derived class we are handling at any given moment. Simply having an object of a class that inherits from `Base` guarantees that we have such a thing as `id`, however the value varies, not depending on the object as an instance, but simply on the class of the object.

Comment: Show us the code instead of just code description.

Comment: *"It has to be a compile-time constant"* - If you use run-time polymorphism, this requirement is incompatible with it.

Comment: Maybe describe the use case as well, it might (or not – but the nature of the question suggests at least…) be a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Hm... A pure `virtual constexpr` function would be first thing coming to my mind – with immediate doubts if being legal at all. Interestingly, gcc accepts while clang rejects, see [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/acbz69Ea3) – even with `-std=c++20` added to avoid a GNU extension being active, yet missing at the link.

Comment: What is a "static virtual getter"? `static` and `virtual` don't mix at all.

Comment: Not quite clear what you want to do? Should it be a  compile-time constant  if you use  derived class as static type?

Comment: Throwing in [`typeid`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid) (-> `std::type_info`, maybe wrapped into `std::type_index`) – leaving up to you to decide if feasible ;)

Comment: How many id's do you actually need? Assume you have `Variant1_1 : public Variant1` and `Variant1_2 : public Variant1` – would these need to get separate ids or share the one of `Variant1`?

Comment: @Aconcagua Not sure about further derivation, hasn't been on the table yet.  Either way will do for now. `typeid` is nice but my IDs come from outside and I don't choose them. Would you use `typeid` to access an external array of possible IDs ? I was precisely trying to avoid that and have a nicer presentation and the possibility to just say `Base::id` and get the derived value.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie Don't understand the question, especially "if you use derived class as **static type**" what is 'static type' here ?

Comment: Type known at time of compilation. Using `Derived d; d.getter();` versus `Base *p = Derived; p->getter()` where type is known at run-time. You can't get a constexpr value if you have run-time dispatching, even if you try some magic with pointer to a constant - a  pointer or vtable pointer is always runtime.

Comment: A base class cannot require *anything* from its derived classes, except to implement the same virtual functions the base has.

Comment: @WeijjunZhou Good catch, this suggestion I found is not static and therefore even worse because there might be an instance of `id` with each instance of VariantA/B which is a waste of memory and also meaningless.

Comment: You might try a *non*-virtual `classId` function relying on RTTI information (-> `typeid`) as [here](https://godbolt.org/z/hnc5sonhE) – though testing for a deriving class if that one actually derives from deriving fails, see last test. *And*: No compile-time constant either.

Comment: Note, too, that you simply *cannot* get out a compile time constant from pointer to base anyway, as you never know to which derived class the pointer points to! So coming back to a former question: What's actually the use case?

Comment: *require from the base class that the derived classes give a value for a constant* How would you use it? Please show some example code.  *It has to be a compile-time constant* Why? What would happen it it is not? Also what happens if two classes define the constant having the same value?

Comment: "might be an instance of id with each instance of VariantA/B which is a waste of memory and also meaningless" you cannot make somethign out of nothing. But "waste" there is a single pointer  in vtable, it shouldn't increment.

Comment: By the way: Are you possibly needing these ids for *serialisation* (-> printing out id before object data to be able to select the appropriate type on deserialisation)? If so, then the `typeid` approach is **not** suitable as the hash code is not guaranteed to remain the same across all programme runs (->writing and reading data to/from files, multiple instances communicating with each other, ...)!

Comment: No serialization involved here. Again, I get my class hashes from elsewhere and they are imposed. I just want to be able to manipulate objects that are similar in abstract behavior (but not concrete) and all promise ti have an ID to show for themselves.

Comment: @@Swift-FridayPie Clearly I am missing something. Okay so if you can promise that a non-static const in a class will occupy the same memory regardless of the number of instances (i.e. there will be one single copy of that non-static const) then I am bank on removing `static` - but then how to proceed ?

Comment: In order to avoid an *XY problem* issue here (although, in my opinion we already reached that point), how about you try to explain to us **why** you need an id and perhaps we can think of a way to help you implement it or we could even suggest a better way instead of using ids. If your answer will be "This is the way we have to do it and we won't change it", I am afraid you'll have to face the truth that it *could* be a bad design choice. Aconcagua beat me to it as I too, thought it's used for serialization. Also, you implement the class in C++ but the id is from "elsewhere"? Why?

Comment: "if you can promise that a non-static const in a class will occupy the same memory regardless of the number of instances". That can certainly be done via a reference-to-const member. The point is whether you consider that a viable option, because the  pointer that the compiler uses to implement the reference may occupy larger memory than the const itself and you seem to be very concerned about memory footprint. If you don't want to pay any extra cost, the only option is to reuse the info already present in the vptr, and then you are only left with the options of typeinfo and virtual functions.

Comment: It remains now important to tell how you are going to use these ids! Do you want to retrieve them from any pointers or references to base class(es)? Then there won't be many options left apart from a virtual function! Probably the base class should have it pure virtual to enforce deriving classes override it. Otherwise a template solution comes to my mind, base template left unimplemented, and specialisations for every class in question could provide the value from *'elsewhere'*. If such a specialisation is forgotten, code won't compile (unless the specialisation is not used anywhere anyway).

Comment: @TheNomad I think I see what you mean. So the ID is involved to run an OS command which will provide data, and the command imposes the ID - different company. Depending on the ID, the data will be different in format. The `doSomething` method is actually there to parse this different data format, and fill the data containers specific to each derived class accordingly.
The command however is the same up to this ID. So I'd like to have some common code in the base class to generate and run it.

Comment: @Aconcagua As far as retrieving the IDs I haven't thought so far down the line, clearly I still need to do some more design. Probably though I'll be handling objects (or pointers or references to them) of the base class.

Comment: @Charles Have you considered using a database for a command-id equivalence instead of hardcoding it or using a magic number? Keep in mind, in the long run you might leave the company and some poor guy will need to understand what `478391` means and then imagine why that would mean `command X with param Y`. You don't need to upscale to Oracle or such, even a simple friendly DB such as sqllite might be better.

Comment: @Charles One example approach which is not necessarily the best, but to give you an idea. Say you have your classes `Base`, `CompA1stCmd`, `CompA2ndCmd`, `CompB1stCmd`, each with *your own Ids*, so not some external magic number. Then make a table in sqllite (or whatever DB) where you have all external Ids and their equivalent command and a description (this serves as a simple for of documentation). Then another table with 2 columns, on with the external Ids (from the prev table), the second with your own C++ Ids from your classes. Then just query once in a `static` function in each class.

Comment: Woah I mean thanks but this is Thor's hammer to swat a fly. I only have 10 different IDs tops, they are just super specific. But since the data parsing/decoding and data holders were quite different I thought of making different classes.

Comment: Sorry, but the way you presented this and said *"different companies"* it sounded like you have implementation with at leas 3-4 and each having at least 5-6 commands each with 5-6 parameters. The example in the post was also a bit misleading. I iamgined something a little more upscale. Well, for 10 ids, I think you can just make a *getter* function with a hardcoded value for each class and that's it. Unless you get the ids using web services or other web API function calls. Otherwise it sounds like you might over-complicate it, though not as much as my Thor's Hammer :)

Comment: Different company simply meant : I must write a command of the format `tool.exe -arg1 <arg1> --arg2 <arg2> --id <id>` and I do not have a choice of ID as `tool` is procured externally. But I want to reuse my code that builds the rest of the command, but just inserts the proper ID depending on why type of object we are dealing with.

Comment: Hm... A simple header with the ids defined might do the trick, something like `uint32_t constexpr IdClassX = 123; uint32_t constexpr IdClassY = 456; /*...*/`. Remains open how to manage the data then, could simply be a switch-block, or maybe a pre-filled `std::map` or its unordered variant. Yet another issue might arise if these ids might change over the time. If so, you wouldn't want to change the hard-coded ids, which is where the database (-> @TheNomad) comes into play again, though a simple .ini file might suffice then.

Comment: IDs never change. Your suggestion means that there is one switch block every time I want to loop over all my objects and do something with them. Actually the ID is not used solely for the command, I use it elsewhere to manage cache, folder structure ...

Answer (score 0):

Within these constraints you cannot do better than a virtual getter (which means
run-time):

```
struct Base {
          enum { idN = 0 };
          virtual int id() { return idN; }
};

struct Derived : Base {
          enum { idN = Base::idN + 1 };
          int id() override { return idN; } // note: it's actually  Derived::idN
};
```

If that is meant for use only inside of a base class implementation,the very idea is a sign of flawed design - something is becoming a "god class" there. You rather should do behaviour injection. As your concern is used memory I sugges to look at Flyweight pattern, perhaps it's what you actually need instead of managing individual "small objects".

Comment: I do not understand the `enum` syntax here. Again, I get my class IDs from elsewhere and they are imposed.

Comment: He used your example where you defined the id for each type and gave you a "compilable" and acceptable way to implement it. Consider it an example. For this strict xample, it's a more or less "non-standard" (there is a long discussion here, so his usage is by no means to be considered "illegal C++" or wrong) way to use the enum similar to a constant int.

Comment: @TheNomad it's more or less just a stylistic approach born in pre-C++11 era and used by multiple libraries and corporate guidelines. Nokia and Google are notorious abusers of that. It's a little too wordy and confusing to write `static constexpr const int id= 0` and for a novice it is is unclear is a variable or not. Modern addition of modules complicate matters even more. enum simply provides a `numeric literal`. `enum` practically works on every existing compiler, even on many before C++98 era (or some edgy embedded implementations, which would make a static const a  variable).

Comment: @Charles an anonymous `enum`. if your class ID is some compile-time constant, you can use it directly instead.  In this example `idN` is guaranteed to be compile time

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie I know, I saw it before, also heavily used in game engines with Macro Magic (Unreal Engine 1 and 2 mostly), but considering he never saw this before, I tried to explain it as basic as possible to him. This is also why I said it's a long discussion on the topic and didn't bring in `enum class`es :) I am still curious what the purpose of this is, as he isn't telling us how and why, just that he wants it *like that*. And the point of getting the ids from *elsewhere* sounds like weird third party implementation black magic (some web-api calls or web services maybe?).

Comment: @TheNomad we can only guess... i could imagine sime kind of protobuf, modBUS/CAN bus data wrapper, a WinRT library... but there these things are solved otherwise